# Why does this while loop make the program print out my sentence infinite times?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
x = 1
while True:
    print("This is line number %d"%(x))
    x += 1
```

It seems logical to me that I equal x with number 1. So the next line says: "While it's true that x equals one, print out this sentence.".. But then I put the line "x += 1", which means that x will get bigger everytime... So x should be equal to number 2 the second time around, so "x = 1" is NOT True, so why does it still keep printing then? I don't undertsand While loops very well so if someone could explain it to me it would be great!

Comment: while **True**: /  Did you mean `while x == 1:` ?

Comment: you said "So the next line says: While it's true that x equals one, ". What you say is **wrong**. The next line only says `while True:`. True is a boolean value. Just like 1 is an integer value. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the condition after the `while`. In your case the condition `True` is, of course, always `True`, which is why you get an infinite loop.

Also be sure not to confuse assignment (`=`)  with comparison (`==`).

```
x = 1         <-- assign 1 to x
while x == 1: <-- check if x is equal to 1
    print("This is line number %d" % x)
    x += 1
print(x)      <-- outputs "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of **While True**.

In each iteration the condition will be checked and the condition for **WHILE** loop is always `True`. Being the condition to be true, the loop goes on and on. Thus you are getting infinite loop.

Comment: So everytime I use while loop as "While True:", I will ALWAYS get an infinite loop? And if I were to put something like "While (x < 4):", I would get a loop that stops at one point?

Comment: @Tymu888 Yes you will get infinite loop